# Show that the set S is a countable set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**Q: Show that the set S is a countable set if there is a function $f$ from $S$ to the positive integers such that $f^-1(j)$ is countable whenever $j$ is a positive integer.**

I am not sure about my answer. It is different from the answer in the textbook. So, please advise me with your feedback.

Since the elements of S are countable when $j$ is a positive integer, S must be in the form:

$S=\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}...\}$.

and each elements can be listed by each positive integers. For example, $f^{-1}(1), f^{-1}(2), ...,f^{-1}(n).$

Hence, there are countable number of countable sets in $S$.

Hence, proved.

The answer in the textbook says that since $f^{-1}(j)$ is countable, $S=f^{-1}(1)\cup f^{-1}(2)\cup...$. A countable union of countable sets is countable. Hence, proved.

But I think the answer is wrong because $f^{-1}(1)\cup f^{-1}(2)\cup...=\{x\}\cup \{y\}\cup...=\{x,y,xy, ...\}$ whereas $S=\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}...\}$.

Comment: The book is right. $S=\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}...\}$.  does not make sense.

Comment: "Since the elements of S are countable when $j$ is a positive integer": not "the elements of S", as you write, but "$f^{-1}(j)$", as they write, or more correctly: $f^{-1}(\{j\}),$ i.e. the subset of $S$ consisting of the element(s) mapped by $f$ to $j.$

Comment: $\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}...\}\ne\{x,y,xy...\}.$

Comment: "Since the elements of S are countable [...], S must be in the form: $S=\{\{x\}, \{y\}, \{x,y\}...\}$": no.

Comment: My idea is that because $f^{-1}(j)$ is the element of S, and it is countable, $f^{-1}(j)$ is a set. (This is because it is impossible to state that a number is countable.)

Comment: There are times when we use the same notation to mean different things. A function $f$ only has an inverse if it is one-to-one (ignoring issues about domains and codomains). Only when $f$ is one-to-one is there an actual function $f^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}(j)$ refers to an element of $S$. However, we also use $f^{-1}(j)$ to represent the *set* $\{x \in S\mid f(x) = j\}$, and this is defined whether $f$ is one-to-one or not. Since in the assumptions of the question, there is nothing that requires $f$ to be one-to-one, that set interpretation is clearly the intended one.

Comment: Got it. The symbol has two meanings. I didn't know that before, so I was so confused... Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a solid example to show how this result can be used to show a set is countable. Hopefully this will give you a better understanding about what the question is saying.

The set in question is $\Bbb Q$. Every rational number $r$ has a unique expression as $r = \frac pq$ where $p,q\in \Bbb Z, q > 0$ and $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Define $f(r) = q$. Then for each $n \in \Bbb N^+$, $$f^{-1}(n) =\left\{ \frac mn\ \middle|\ m\in \Bbb Z, \gcd(m,n) = 1\right\}$$
In particular, $f^{-1}(n) \subseteq \Bbb Z$, and thus must be countable. By the result in the question, $\Bbb Q$ is countable as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The proof in Your Textbook is as follows

Consider the set, $f^{-1}(j)=\{x  \in S: f(x)=j\}$

and then look the $$\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty}f^{-1}(j)$$
This is a union of countable number of sets, It is easy to check that $$S=\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty}f^{-1}(j)$$
And we know that each of the $f^-1(j)$ is countable.

Therefore, by the result "Countable Union of Countable sets is countable" We can conclude S is a countable set.

> Now answering you question

I think you have problem in either understanding what $f^{-1}(j)$ means or in understanding the countable union of countable sets is countable..

1. $f^{-1}(j):=\{x \in S: f(x)=j \}$, This is the definition of this set...i.e we are listing all the elements in domain which maps to $j$. That's it.
2. look about the rationals and the  Proof of
   "$\mathbb{Q}$ is countable", It will help you understand more about countablility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I'm trying to understand your solution...Not meaning that your explanation was bad, but I am a bit confused, so I need some time I think.